# How to open PDF's with Open Office?

Tags: pdf, openoffice

Using Open Office 3.1.1 for Mac (OS X 10.5.8) and trying to open PDF's.  Found the Sun PDF import extension, downloaded but can't seem to get the thing to work - am i just being daft?  Tried opening the .zip file with OO as it says in the 'Comments' on the download page only to get a big list of filters that doesn't contain PDF or ODF/PDF Hybrid.  If i unzip the download, which file do i use?

Help much appreciated.

Comment: Update - managed to install the PDF extension manager but can't open any PDF's.  I just get a pop-up 'General Error.  General input/output error.'

Help!

Comment: Update - 

Fixed it! :) Removed & deleted all previous attempts, went back to the download page, clicked the 'details' link instead and then 'Get It' from that page instead. The download now has the proper Open Office extention 'jigsaw piece' icon (all previous downloads just had generic icons) and opened & installed fine. PDF's open & edit great. 'Tis a happy day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Open Office and chose File->Open and there change file type to PDF (default is all files), this is the only way I can open an pdf with open office (after I add Sun PDF import extension!).

Comment: Cheers.  Worked after adding the PDF extension from the Open Office site.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read PDF files but don't want to have the 'heavyweight' Adobe Acrobat as your viewer, you could try Sumatra PDF reader. it is small, fast and open-source, and isn't bogged down by bloat.

http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/

Comment: Thanks very much for the suggestion,need to be able to edit PDF's too though.

Answer (score 0):

The success of the import heavily depends on the documents complexity, have a look at oo-wiki pages. PDF import is beta v 0.4 at the moment

Answer (score 0):

I just grabbed a PDF (written by pdfTeX, probably LaTeX source) to cut out an image using LibreOffice's oodraw. No problems.

What do you need to do to the PDF? Perhaps less heavy-handed tools are enough?